# Hiding built-in field in "Edit Properties" form trough Content Type definition xml file

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We need to hide some of the built-in field of our Pages in the "Edit Properties" form.

I tried to hide the fields in the content type file using `Hidden="TRUE"`, `ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE"` etc, but it does not seem to work.

Also, we have a content type hierarchy, so the fields would be "hidden" in our main content type that all concrete content types inherit from.

I would like to avoid having to create some edit form for each of our content type, if possible, so something generic and hierarchical would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention ShowInDisplayForm, but have you tried [ShowInEditForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showineditform%28v=office.12%29.aspx)?

I've never tried ShowInEditForm in a Content Type, although it appears to be [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543225%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Whenever I have used ShowInEditForm, it has been with the Field definition, the List Template schema.xml, or both. But it has always worked as expected. The field is removed from the Edit Form.

As far as Content Type inheritance, the property value should persist as long as no other child Content Type or List Template overrides your setting.

Comment: Actually, it works for all the built in types, except Content Type, that was the one I was trying to hide...

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Content-Type from the EditForm, you have to follow another procedure that is described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmp/archive/2009/01/26/how-to-hide-content-type-choice-control-in-edit-forms.aspx